# How to check if a variable exists in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have code that loops, and I want to initialize the variable one within the code. To do this, I check if the variable exists, and if not, initialize it.

In JavaScript, I would normally just do the following

```
if (typeof variableExample === 'undefined') {
    // run this code
}
```

But TypeScript doesn't like this. It tells me that it can't perform this because it cannot find the variable:
[image]

Any ideas for getting around this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Sound like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: You can't, because it's not a very good programming practice (which is why it's not accepted by Typescript). Always initialize your variables.

Comment: Are you talking about global variables?

Comment: This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You *should not have* "conditional variables". In fact, you *cannot* here: `const` and `let` are block scoped, so you cannot initialise them on, say, loop 2 or and then have them available later as the variable won't be available outside the `if`. And definitely not across loops. . While `var` *may* work "outside the if" and "across loops" (in heavy quotes) but it's not because it's definied *inside* the `if` - `var` declarations are hoisted - by the time the loop runs the variable exitsts

Comment: If it's a global variable you can try to check `typeof window.testVar === 'undefined'`, but again, Typescript is useful for type check, it has no points to skip that type check

Comment: The code in the question isn't even the same as the code in the picture in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think a better approach to do this would be to first declare the variable outside of the loop and initialize inside if `null` or `undefined`

```
let myVar;
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if(myVar == null) {
    myVar = 1
  }
}
```

Of course doing so in this example seems unnecessary but I hope it helps you map it to your use case

Answer (score 1):

> To do this, I check if the variable exists, and if not, initialize it.

Variables that only conditionally exist aren't the TypeScript way, and it's generally not a good idea even in JavaScript.

There's a difference between *declaring* a variable (creating it, making it exist) and *initializing* the variable (giving it an initial value). TypeScript is complaining because you haven't declared the variable.

To solve that, declare it (`let` or `const`). If you **really** want the variable to start out with the value `undefined`, you can make that part of its type:

```typescript
let testVar: undefined | number; // Initial value defaults to `undefined`,
                                 // though adding = undefined for clarity may
                                 // be good
```

(I think there's also a flag that lets you have `undefined` in its type implicitly, but I wouldn't use that flag.)

Then when your code is ready to see if it needs to set the value on it, it can use `typeof testVar === "undefined"` (or just `testVar === undefined`):

```typescript
if (typeof testVar === "undefined") {
    testVar = 1;
}
```

...or the nullish coalescing operator:

```typescript
testVar = testVar ?? 1;
```

[Playground showing all three](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBGIM5gagQwE4C4IFcB2ATEAzASyxBwgB8IsMBbAIxGQG4BYAKHYHpOIBVGYgHMIAAzABPAA4gA9vhHtC+CAAoAsojAALAHTJEuGTRUBKCAB4IABh0BWMwG92EFxCWqJ0uVFgIUEAF4gzFwCYlJHZ1do6DgkZECIAEZWNmiAX3ZMjjZuPgEsYUQIADdEYAwQCABjI0kUQhgZLEVldU1dfUNjM0sbewgnNNd3FVi-BKCAkLwiEhxI4eiXcfjElKiXbOyuHn4hKgxgYEatGply2GqhVtUNbT0DHCNTC2s7RZjfNenV-wB+f7JVLpIA)

But only do that if you really can't assign a meaningful value to the variable where you declare it, which is rare, and which in many cases should suggest to you that you need to put the variable in a narrower scope or otherwise refactor.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's the "TypeScript way", sometimes you just need to write code that tolerates different runtime environments

Answer (score -1):

A practical example of two variables and the use of typeof should be enough to know if a variable exists or not.

```html
<script>
let x;

console.log(typeof x);  // <- declared variable
console.log(typeof y);  // <- undeclared variable

if(!x) console.log("x is null");
if(!y) console.log("y doesn't exists"); // Ooooopsss, ReferenceError
</script>
```